# Azure Pipelines - CI Trigger on feature branch doest work with YAML

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

CI doesn't trigger when I change anything in my feature/* branch. I configured a YAML on Azure pipeline -

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
     - feature/*
```

I also tried the other style of configuration - again unsuccessful

```
 trigger:
  - feature/*
```

Also tried with the complete feature name like `feature/my-feature`

However when I override the YAML trigger and use branch filters to point to the specific feature branch the CI works when I make changes in the branch.

I followed [this official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Azure Pipelines - CI Trigger on feature branch doest work with YAML

You should set the yaml file in **one of branch** under the `feature` folder.

Since you set the trigger with `feature/*`, but there is no branch named `feature`, we could not set the the yaml file in `feature` brance of the repo. So, we need to set the the yaml file in **one of branch** under the `feature` folder, like: `feature/Test`.

[image]

In this case, when I change anything in my `feature/*` branch, like `feature/Test2`, it will trigger this pipeline.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This works.  Is this limitation documented or is it a defect ?

Comment: @Abdul, Yes, this is YAML limitation.

Comment: But wouldn't this just work for Feature/Test and not new features ?

Answer (score 0):

the one reason this could happen - the yaml file is not present in the feature branch. the decision to trigger the build or not comes when a commit is pushed to a branch, based on the content of the yaml file in the branch. if the file is not there, obviosuly nothing will be built.