# Azure DevOps branch/pipeline setup for Dev and Release and hotfix branches

Tags: azure-devops

I am having difficulty in setting up my project for dev and release work. I have gone through various articles but I am unable to come to a definitive conclusion about how to setup up my dev and release pipelines for different branches. I need help in this area.

As an example, say I have a Dev branch with a pipeline DevPipeline in /azure-pipelines.yml.
This pipeline has CI triggers like so:

```
trigger:

Dev
features/*
```

1. Now, when I create a branch Release/R1.0 what exactly do I need to do?
2. Do I create a new pipeline say Release-R1.0. Where should the .yml for this pipeline be?
3. Should it overwrite /azure-pipelines.yml or should I create /Release-R1.0.yml?
4. If developers want to work on a fix/hotfix for R1.0, should they work under hotfix/R1.0 branch? In this case, I would have to adjust my triggers accordingly in the R1.0 yaml?

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Now, when I create a branch Release/R1.0 what exactly do I need to do?
> 2. Do I create a new pipeline say Release-R1.0. Where should the .yml for this pipeline be?

It depends on whether your new created pipeline has the same build as the pipeline on the `Dev` branch. If yes, you can just add one more trigger `Release/R1.0` in the `azure-pipelines.yml`:

```
trigger:

Dev
features/*
Release/R1.0
```

If they do not have the same pipeline, or you do not want use the same pipeline for the branch `Release/R1.0`, you need to create a new pipeline say `Release-R1.0`. And **the `.yml` for this pipeline should be set** the `yaml` file in `R1.0` branch under the `Release` folder. Check [my previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59459461/azure-pipelines-ci-trigger-on-feature-branch-doest-work-with-yaml) for some details.

> Should it overwrite /azure-pipelines.yml or should I create
>   /Release-R1.0.yml?

Since they have different triggers or different build tasks, it should not overwrite `/azure-pipelines.yml`, you need create a new `/Release-R1.0.yml`.

> If developers want to work on a fix/hotfix for R1.0, should they work
>   under hotfix/R1.0 branch? In this case, I would have to adjust my
>   triggers accordingly in the R1.0 yaml?

If I understand you correct, if you want to work on a hotfix for `R1.0`, it is better to create a branch `Release/hotfix-R1.0` based on the `R1.0`, and in the R1.0 yaml, you could set the triggers:

```
trigger:
Release/*
```

So, you do not have to adjust my triggers accordingly in the `R1.0` yaml.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. This is certainly very helpful info. I think I am in favor of having a separate pipeline for Release 1.0 branch, even though at the moment I won't be having any different build tasks. This is because I will have different version numbers. I tried using condition expressions to have a common pipeline, but got hung up with custom build numbers. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/872081/custom-build-run-number.html?childToView=875741#comment-875741

Comment: I am trying to understand this in the context of Release Flow & Trunk based development. This is as per the article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/learn/devops-at-microsoft/release-flow, where the release branch is completely dispensable. The core concept from my understanding that all changes are to be made in the master branch/trunk and then cherry picked into the release branch (well, almost all). If I overlay this concept onto your response, then IMO the Release/R1.0 branch and it's .yaml will be in master branch also. Is that correct understanding?

Comment: @Chubsdad, I am afraid not. This question is different  from fourth question in the post. That question is **have to adjust your triggers**, but if you follow the Release Flow & Trunk based development process, it is better not to set Release/R1.0 branch and it's .yaml will be in master branch, any change in the master trigger the release is not recommended. The correct way is all changes are to be made in the master branch, then create a pull request to merge changes from master to release, then it trigger the release to be deploy.

Comment: Let us take my situation where my Release R1.0 will be on .net framework 4.7 and master branch (and further releases) will be on dotnet core 3.1. In that case, my pipelines are going to be different(different tool chains). What is the recommendation here given that Release R1.0 must be a long running branch in my situation. I am confused. I am probably going around in circles but I am having difficulty in connecting all the dots.

Comment: @Chubsdad, Since they are in the different target framework, and  Release R1.0 must be a long running branch in your situation, why not consider creating a new release branch, like Release R2.0 based on master on dotnet core 3.1?

Comment: `-dev
    -yaml
         - dev.yml  (trigger: dev, features/*)
         - R1.0.yml (trigger: exclude release/R1.0, exclude bugfix/R1.0/*, exclude hotfix/R1.0/*, exclude features/R1.0/*)

-R1.0
    -yaml
         - dev.yml  (trigger: exclude dev, exclude features/*)
         - R1.0.yml (trigger: release/R1.0, bugfix/R1.0/*, hotfix/R1.0/*, features/R1.0/*)`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know exactly how to put preformatted text here, but does that represent an accurate understanding of what we are discussing?

Comment: @Chubsdad, Since the question in the comment is different from the previous in your question, I suggest that you can open a new thread with some detailed info about the new question, so that we could understand your more clear.

Comment: Makes sense. Here's the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59622046/azure-pipelines-release-flow-and-trunk-based-development

Comment: Can you please put your thoughts on the new question which I created as per your suggestion?

Comment: @Chubsdad, Sorry, I was invited to another thread, my colleague will help you to check it as soon as possible, and I will check it when I free.

Comment: hi, please let me know if you are waiting for any additional inputs from me on my new question