# Azure Pipelines: Release Flow and Trunk based Development

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

This question is closely linked to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59606427/azure-devops-branch-pipeline-setup-for-dev-and-release-and-hotfix-branches)

Given, that I am opting to go for Release Flow and Trunk based Development in Azure DevOps, how should I be arranging my pipelines and yamls (pseudocode yaml). Here is what I think based on the previous SO question above.

```
-Branch dev
    -yaml
         - dev.yml  (trigger: dev, features/*) for pipeline Development
         - R1.0.yml (trigger: release/R1.0, bugfix/R1.0/*, hotfix/R1.0/*, features/R1.0/*) for pipeline ReleaseR1.0

-Branch R1.0
    -yaml
         - dev.yml  (trigger: dev, features/*)  for pipeline Development
         - R1.0.yml (trigger: release/R1.0, bugfix/R1.0/*, hotfix/R1.0/*, features/R1.0/*) for pipeline ReleaseR1.0
```

1. Is this accurate, or is there something I am missing?
2. Are there any best practices here?
3. While cherry picking from master to
   release, any pipeline changes can't be cherry picked as is, if the
   pipelines diverge (e.g. .net framework upgrade between master and
   R1.0). They will have to be adjusted according to the pipeline
   definitions in R1. Is that accurate?
4. Are there articles on lines of patterns and antipatterns for Azure DevOps and Pipelines? They have been very helpful in the software engineering world in specific and other disciplines in general.

Comment: @user:7460777: Please suggest

Comment: For your previous 2 question, based on my opinion, it is accurate. Just about your puzzle which mentioned in third question, if what you worry about is the cherry pick would have affect on the pipeline in release branch, just be assured because  if the commits node which be cherry picked contain any changes on the pipeline definition, it will prompt you the conflict error. **patterns and antipatterns**, could you express exactly about this? Little confused about this.